# Calculating body style height (for horizontal scroll) in javascript not working

Tags: javascript, css

I'm sure this is something blindingly obvious, but I'm trying to run a calculation to get the body height exactly right so it doesn't leave a gap at the end of the wrapper.

I've been staring at this thing for so long I can't see what I'm missing, because the output from the calculation isn't actually altering the css like it should.

Here's the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cfebsdu8/)

```
const body = document.querySelector("body");
const wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper");
const bodyHeight = function() {
  body.style.height =
    wrapper.offsetWidth - (window.innerWidth - window.innerHeight);
};

bodyHeight();
window.addEventListener("resize", bodyHeight);
document.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  let scroll = window.pageYOffset;
  wrapper.style.left = `${-1 * scroll}px`;
});
```

Comment: "Blindingly Obvious" Most of the time, this is the case for my problems haha.

Answer (score 3):

add `px`

`body.style.height = wrapper.offsetWidth - (window.innerWidth - window.innerHeight) +'px'`